# Click event in dynamically Selected elements charged by ajax with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, css-selectors

I need to capture the click event of an element charged with ajax in a table.

After get the dynamic content, I can see the alert result with total number of elements with: alert($(".link").length);

All of elements that I select have the class "link", I need to know which of this elements was clicked.

I've tried ->  $(".link").click(function()...     but I discovered that just elements that already exists are captured. All of the elements charged by ajax are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Could use some code to be 100% sure, but this works and with fiddle.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="list"><td>One</td></tr>
    <tr class="list"><td>Two</td></tr>
    <tr class="list"><td>Three</td></tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$("table").delegate('.list', 'click', function() {  
    var whichOne = $(this).text();
    alert("Handler for .click() called for " + whichOne);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ADg2P/2/

UPDATE: Use delegate instead, missed the ajax part.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `on` method jQuery provides; or `live` if you're using an older version of jQuery. Reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

The binding step would look like this:

```
$('.link').on('click', function() {
   // your code here
});
```

This will bind existing elements, as well as new ones provided by AJAX, to the click event you specify.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `on` method if you're using jQuery 1.7+.

Have a read of this excellent article - http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html

Comment: Thank You very much! I used:

     $("#strRowsTable").on("click", ".link", function(){